# How to select one field based on another field, and then subtract any with more than 1 result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so I have been looking everywhere and i cant seem to find anything. 
Heres what Im trying to do:

```
SELECT SFirstName, SLastName
FROM Advisors
WHERE Students <= ('1') and Students.AdvisorID=Advisors.AdvisorID;
```

The SName is student names, and i need to basically list advisors based on the number of active students for each, and then filter out any with more than one student.

Heres an attempt to code this with the DBO names and all.

```
SELECT AFirstName, ALastName
FROM DBO.Students, DBO.Advisors
WHERE Advisor.AdvisorID=Student.AdvisorID AND >1;
```

Basically the advisorID is a Foreign Key within the Students table, and I need to match it with the advisor table and then the >1 statement. I dont know how to reduce results by number yet however.

Whenever I try this it tells me it cannot find the advisor.advisorID or the student.AdvisorID. how would i do this while still using the foreign key from one and the primary key from the other to cross check matches.

Comment: Please post table definitions or sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to list the `Advisors` with less than 1 `Students`. If so, what you need is a `LEFT JOIN` coupled with `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    a.AFirstName, a.ALastName
FROM dbo.Student s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Advisors a
    ON a.AdvisorID = s.AdvisorID
GROUP BY
    a.AdvisorID, a.AFirstName, a.ALastName
HAVING
    COUNT(s.AdvisorID) <= 1
```

Notes:

- [Avoid using the old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- Alias your tables to improve readability.

Comment: Wow FAST. Okay it seems to be exactly what I need to do from what I understand from reviewing Left Join right now. Where to the ON.(a).AdvisorID come from? is that the first letter of the table its within or would i use the full name of the table to comment that?

Comment: SUCCESS! By the way. Worked perfectly. i dont understand what the a and the s at the end of the from and left join columns are for though. Can you explain?

Comment: It's called "aliasing", it just says "whenever I use "s." know that I'm really saying "dbo.Students.", but I don't want to write it out all the time".

Comment: OH! Wow, thats useful. I hadnt realized this was a feature. so does it have to be lowercase? or can it be a string?